# Angular 8: Jasmine Unit Test on ActivatedRoute, TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

In my Angular 8 application, A component is having an ActivatedRoute class and on the ngOnInit, I am subscribing the route. I have mocked ActivatedRoute in my spec.ts file but cannot set the parent property since it is read-only. It is showing a TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined
How can we unit test ActivatedRoute in spec.ts?

Here is a code snippet

```
ngOnInit() {
this.subscriptions.add(this.route.parent.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams =>{ 
this.Type = queryParams .type 
}))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mock your `ActivatedRoute` as follows:

```
const queryParams = new QueryParams();
queryParams.set('type', '?');

const activatedRouteMock = {
   parent: { queryParams: of(queryParams) }
};
```

The mock would then have to be provided when configuring the testing module inside `beforeEach`.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRouteMock } }
    ]
    ....
});
```

For setting up the `activatedRouteMock`  I use `QueryParams` test class for convenience.

```
import { ParamMap } from '@angular/router';

export class QueryParams implements ParamMap {

   readonly keys: string[] = [];
   private params = new Map();

   set(name: string, value: string) {
      this.keys.push(name);
      this.params.set(name, value);
   }

   get(name: string): string | null {
      return this.has(name) ? this.params.get(name) : null;
   }

   has(name: string): boolean {
      return this.params.has(name);
   }

   getAll(name: string): string[] {
      return this.params.has(name) ? [this.params.get(name)] : [];
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In your comment you write, that this doesn't work for the following line of code.

```
this.subscriptions.add(this.route.parent.parent.parent.params.subscribe(params => { this.Id = params.Id})
```

This is because here, you chain references to `parent` objects. Therefore your `activatedRouteMock` must contain more than one nested parent objects as well.

```
const activatedRouteMock = {
  parent: {
    queryParams: of(queryParams),
    parent: {
      parent: { params: of(queryParams) }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: ```this.subscriptions.add(this.route.parent.parent.parent.params.subscribe(params => {
this.Id = params.Id})```
For queryParams this works fine for me. I used the same approach as above for this line of code as well but getting an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined

Comment: @DDK: I updated my answer showing an approach that should also work for the line you mentioned.